# How to read this piece of code containing 'nibabel'?

Tags: python-3.x

I have to work with code from someone else. The code relates to 
`NiBabel` a program/lib for ***Access a cacophony of neuro-imaging file formats*** and I can't really grasp what the following piece of code does:

```
folderData = os.path.dirname(ground_truth_path)
result = os.path.join(folderData, name + '.nii.gz')
nib.save(nib.Nifti1Image(Seg, nib.load(ground_truth_path).affine),result)
```

Note: 'name' is given as the input of the function where this piece of code belongs to.

I think the first line gives the directory of the given path and the second line adds something to this directory. But I can't really see what happens in the third line. Anybody who can explain?

Comment: What is `nib`? Where did that come from?

Comment: Did you check the API from [here](https://nipy.org/nibabel/api.html#api)?

Comment: @Jesse, updated answer. It would be nice if you respond to my answer and or upvote the answer. If its not satisfying then explain what is still unanswered.

Answer (score 1):

The following line debunked:

`nib.save(nib.Nifti1Image(Seg, nib.load(ground_truth_path).affine),result)`

nib.save = saving processed image segment or image to filepath "result":
                      `(nib.Nifti1Image(Seg, nib.load(ground_truth_path).affine),result)`

1. `nib.Nifti1Image` = Nifti1Image(dataobj, affine[, header, …]) a Class for single file NIfTI1 format image.
2. `nib.load(ground_truth_path).affine` = load segmentation information from given path and apply image segmentation transformation.
3. `(Seg, nib.load(ground_truth_path).affine)` = perform a retrieve datasegment from image (located at result)? 'Seg is is a typo. See also [here](https://www.programcreek.com/python/example/98176/nibabel.load) where `seg = nib.load..etc`. See below for correction.
4. `.affine` = affine transformation that determines the world-coordinates of the image elements.
5. `result` = Image location for result.

The code is missing a bracket and includes 'seg' typo and should be:

> new = `nib.save(nib.Nifti1Image((nib.load(ground_truth_path).affine),result))`

old = `nib.save(nib.Nifti1Image(Seg, nib.load(ground_truth_path).affine),result)`